# Get frequencies from counts, with multiple levels of grouping

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like the following:

```
df <- data.frame(group1=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                 group2 = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y","X", "X", "Y", "Y"),
                 type = c("a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h"),
                 count = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))

> df
  group1 group2 type count
1      A      X    a     1
2      A      X    b     2
3      A      Y    c     3
4      A      Y    d     4
5      B      X    e     5
6      B      X    f     6
7      B      Y    g     7
8      B      Y    h     8
```

I would like to put the relative frequency of each type, grouped by `group1` and `group2`, into a column. I have a way to do it but it's clunky, requiring summarizing and then joining. I feel like there's got to be a way to do it within one `dplyr` statement. But what I can't figure out is after summarizing, I need to go back to having all the rows.

My clunky way:

```
df.summ <- df %>% group_by(group1, group2) %>% 
  summarize(tot = sum(count))

df <- left_join(df, df.summ)

df <- df %>% mutate(freq = count/tot)

> df
  group1 group2 type count tot      freq
1      A      X    a     1   3 0.3333333
2      A      X    b     2   3 0.6666667
3      A      Y    c     3   7 0.4285714
4      A      Y    d     4   7 0.5714286
5      B      X    e     5  11 0.4545455
6      B      X    f     6  11 0.5454545
7      B      Y    g     7  15 0.4666667
8      B      Y    h     8  15 0.5333333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more direct if we use `mutate` instead of `summarise/left_join` as `summarise` by default returns only a single row per group while `mutate` creates a new column in the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
   group_by(group1, group2) %>%
   mutate(freq = count/sum(count)) %>%
   ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I never realized I could use `mutate` after `group_by`! Can I ask, what does `ungroup` do here? Seems to give the same output with or without it

Comment: @BenS. With `mutate`, the group attributes are not dropped afterwards.  So, if you are not doing any other operation by group (or doing some operations without grouping) then it is not needed and it may even have an adverse effect in some RMD knitting etc

Answer (score 2):

A base R one-liner:

```
df$freq <- with(df, ave(count, list(group1, group2), FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)))
df
#  group1 group2 type count      freq
#1      A      X    a     1 0.3333333
#2      A      X    b     2 0.6666667
#3      A      Y    c     3 0.4285714
#4      A      Y    d     4 0.5714286
#5      B      X    e     5 0.4545455
#6      B      X    f     6 0.5454545
#7      B      Y    g     7 0.4666667
#8      B      Y    h     8 0.5333333
```